# Unity: I can not access to GameObject.SetActive() if there is an Animation that modifies it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am new in Unity and I don't know if I am missing something. I have found this problem repeatedly.

I have a GameObject that I deactivate/activate by code.

The same GameObject is deactivate/activate by animation(s).

Well, this doesn't work.

My commands in code are ignored. Even if the animation is not active right now.

It is easy to see when I am having this issue because while game is in Play I can not modify the active state of the GameObject from the Inspector. Only if I pause the game I can modify the active state in the Inspector but after un-pause the element go backs to the previous state.

I understand that the animation can override whatever is said in code. But I asume that this should happen only when the animation is active.

How can I play with the SetActive() of one GameObject in the animations but also in the code?

Comment: Is there anything else that could be effecting the activity of the game object? Do you have any errors in your console? Are you sure the animation is not playing?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code, or enough about your project for someone to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: You shouldn't mix changes via the animator with runtime changes via script.

It is very easy to lose the overview and you will not anymore know which changes happened because of the animator and which because of a script.

If this is really necessary you should rather use parenting and do e.g.

```
SomeParent
|-- SomeChild
```

and either control the `SomeParent` via the script and the `SomeChild` via Animator or the other way round.

---

As soon as there is an Animator where any animation state holds only any keyframe on a certain property, the Animator "locks" that property against any changes via script since the Animator is executed [almost latest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) within one frame.

---

Try doing your change in `LateUpdate` or via Coroutine via `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` which would be executed after the Animator.

---

Or if possible you could disable the Animator for the time where you want to "manually" overwrite the property via script like

```
_animator.enabled = false;
theObject.SetActive(false);
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, thanks. I understand the Animation occurs at the end.. but this Animation is not active now and it should not `lock` the property. This is very annoying, now I am trying to move the Player position via special Animation (only triggered at some specific situation) but if I manipulate the `position` via Animation (even if is not active now) the Player is not moving any more when I move the Player object via Script :/